# Messenger API Handover Pass Thread Control returning error 10 (2018171)

Tags: facebook, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

We've set up a bot, which features a persistent menu with the option for a user to switch the discussion to a human, by using the Handover Protocol.

This button sends a payload to DialogFlow, which then calls our web hook to post to the Messenger API the following function:

```
request({
    url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/pass_thread_control',
    qs: { access_token: config.page_token },
    method: 'POST',
    json:{
      "recipient": {"id": userID},
      "target_app_id": 263902037430900
    }
  }, (error, res, body) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error('Error sending messages: ', error)
    } else if (res.body.error) {
      console.error('Error: ', res.body.error)
    }
  })
```

But the call returns the following error:

```
{  
  message:'(#10) Only available to Primary and Secondary Receivers',
  type:'OAuthException',
  code:10,
  error_subcode:2018171,
  fbtrace_id:'HUrgr45FGGC'
}
```

We can't figure out this error (which is undocumented).

Under the Page Settings, the bot is correctly set as the primary receiver, and the Inbox as secondary.

Has anyone else run into this?

Comment: Can you verify that the bot app is correctly set up as primary receiver by making this API call, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/handover-protocol/secondary-receivers, with a page access token issued for that same app?

Comment: @CBroe API replies with the following correct data: `{"data":[{"id":"263902037430900","name":"Page Inbox"}]}`

Comment: We switched pages (along with tokens, which have the exact same authorisations), and it seems to have fixed the problem.
So it seems the issue resides on the Facebook side. A bug report has been filed: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/820116014857560/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those getting here via a Google Search : turns out if was a bug on Facebook API, which is now fixed.

➡️ https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/820116014857560